# Command line argument is too long when using Maven's jaxws wsgen plugin because of long classpath

Tags: command-line, classpath, maven-3, wsgen

I'm trying to generate web service artifacts using the `org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons jaxws-maven-plugin` and the `wsgen` goal. It seems that part of the process is to execute a command that includes all the project jars on the classpath and this results in a command that exceeds character limit of the command line by more than double (on Windows 7). How can I workaround this?

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsgen (generate-wsdl) @ interface ---
[INFO] Processing: com.mycompany.myproject.MyWebService
[INFO] jaxws:wsgen args: [-keep, -s, D:\Dev\myproject\target\generated-sources\wsgen, -d, D:\Dev\myproject\target\classes, -encoding, Cp1252, com.mycompany.myproject.MyWebService]
[WARNING] Length of the command is limitted to 8191 characters but it has 15450 characters.
[WARNING] cmd.exe /X /C "D:\java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\java.exe 

-Xbootclasspath/p:
D:\m2repo\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2-b03\javax.annotation-api-1.2-b03.jar;
D:\m2repo\javax\jws\jsr181-api\1.0-MR1\jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar;
D:\m2repo\javax\xml\ws\jaxws-api\2.2.9\jaxws-api-2.2.9.jar;
D:\m2repo\javax\xml\soap\saaj-api\1.3.4\saaj-api-1.3.4.jar;
D:\m2repo\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.7\jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar 

-cp 
/D:/m2repo/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/jaxws-maven-plugin/2.3/jaxws-maven-plugin-2.3.jar org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.Invoker com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool 

-pathfile 
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\jax-ws-mvn-plugin-cp83681795198066117.txt 

-cp 
<long list of project jars from .m2 repository>

-keep 
-s D:\Dev\project\target\generated-sources\wsgen 
-d D:\Dev\project\target\classes 
-encoding Cp1252 

com.mycompany.myproject.MyWebService"

The command line is too long.
```

Comment: Have you got any work-around ? Cause, using 2.3.1-b03 giving me error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether....

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug ([JAX-WS-COMMON-110](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS_COMMONS-110)) that will be fixed in version 2.3.1.

Until jaxws-maven-plugin 2.3.1 is officially released, you may compile it from svn.

```
svn checkout https://svn.java.net/svn/jax-ws-commons~svn/tags/jaxws-maven-plugin-2.3.1-b03
cd jaxws-maven-plugin-2.3.1-b03
mvn install
```

And then update your pom.xml to use the 2.3.1-b03 version:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1-b03</version>
...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build the updated version yourself, it can be downloaded from the Maven repository

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons|jaxws-maven-plugin|2.3.1-b03|maven-plugin